# R loop add another column instead of putting it down (Gephi export)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This part is just for the example.

```
initmatrix <- matrix(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", NA, NA, "I", NA, NA, NA, NA, "J", "K", "L", "M",NA ,"N" ,"O" ,"P" ,NA ,NA), nrow=5, ncol=5) 

initmatrix <- t(initmatrix)
```

This is the key part

```
elisttry <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(initmatrix)){
    temptry <- na.omit(as.character(initmatrix[i,]))
    #if necessary; check matrix for "NA"
    #temp <- temp[-which(temp == "NA")]
    if(length(temptry)>1){
        elisttry <- c(elisttry, combn(temptry,2))
    }
}
```

For this code, the output (elisttry) will be a single column that combines the first element of each row on initmatrix with every other element. In this case, the result will be "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D" and so on.
But i need it to be a two column matrix, like this:

```
> elisttry
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "D"
```

Any insights? Thanks

Comment: how about just `t(matrix(elisttry, nrow=2))` after your cycle?

Comment: wow, that should do it. Nice and easy Vasily. Thanks!!